# Flink metrics on minicluster

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, graphite

Im looking to add graphite metrics to my flink minicluster, but I am quite confused how to begin with this since most of the documentation I can find is on adding metrics to a cluster via the config file. I understand I would need a reporter, but I was wondering if anyone has any pointers to lead me in the right direction:)

Its a pretty open question, so I apologize for that, but hopefully someone has done something similar before me and can help me out a little bit:)